# What is the scriptural stance on taking Datura Stramonium (Jimsonweed)

Tags: scripture, dharma, dharma-shastras, plants

The main reason why Datura is different to the other intoxicants for scriptural reasons is that it is thoroughly unpleasant in terms of recreational use and thus it shouldn't be possible to get addicted to it.

It is also cheap, often legal (due to it not being addictive), and very powerful, causing a waking dream state and thus there are strong reasons to take it if you are looking for something to cause a waking dream state, even if you don't like other drugs.

Anyway, does the scriptural reasons against things like alcohol apply in this case i.e. does the wording of the prohibitions/warnings include datura?